# Language change via laravel-vue-i18n package

Tags: laravel, vue.js, internationalization

Good afternoon, I'm studying Vue and trying to make a multilingual application, I found this package and installed it - https://github.com/xiCO2k/laravel-vue-i18n
I managed to connect it, and the translation works.
But I can't figure out how to do the language change? The documentation says it:

```
import { loadLanguageAsync } from 'laravel-vue-i18n';

<template>
    <div>{{ $t('Welcome!') }}</div>
    <button @click="loadLanguageAsync('pt')">Change to Portuguese Language</button>
</template>
```

, but I don't understand how use it,
What code to use in the method? I will be very grateful to you if you show an example of a method for changing the language.

My app.blade.php

```
<html lang="{{str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale())}}">
```

My langs: en.json | en.json

My vue.js

```
@click="switchLanguageTo('en')"
import {i18nVue, loadLanguageAsync} from 'laravel-vue-i18n';
methods: {
    switchLanguageTo(lang) {
        // here i dont understand 
        loadLanguageAsync(lang);
        //  here i dont understand 
    },
},
```

Answer (score 1):

it's quite simple.

By calling `loadLanguageAsync` function you can change your language immediately.

```js
<script setup>
import { loadLanguageAsync } from 'laravel-vue-i18n';
</script>

<template>
    <h1> {{ $t('Hello World')}} </h1>
    <button class="hover:underline" @click="loadLanguageAsync('fr')"> Change language </button>
</template>
```

/lang/fr.json

```json
{
    "Hello World": "Bonjour le monde"
}
```